# How to ensure that the contents of the list will always sum up to 1?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, probability

I am trying to have a probability list, which I have to renew all the time when a new element joins. My code is:

```
sum=7
my_list = [2,2,2,1]
prob_list = list(map(lambda x: float(x/sum), my_list))
```

Which yields:

```
>>prob_list
[0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857, 0.14285714285714285]
```

And when I check the sum of the elements of prob_list, it sums up to 1 perfectly:

```
0,2857142857142857+ 0,2857142857142857+ 0,2857142857142857+0,14285714285714285 = 1
```

However, when I use this file in numpy.random.choice, it raises an error by saying that probabilities do not add up to 1:

```
k = choice(my_list, size=1,replace=False, p=prob_list)[0]
```

The error is:

*k = choice(my_list, size=1,replace=False, p=prob_list)[0] File "mtrand.pyx", line 1130, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:17766)*

*ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1*

Do you know the reason of the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: It works fine for me. What's your NumPy/Python version?

Comment: Also `sum` is a builtin-function, so better choose another variable name, so it doesn't shadow the builtin `sum`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same Python version everywhere? 2 and 3 are incompatible.

Comment: Why don't you post your real code. Since you have shadowed sum, you can't be checking the sum of your list as you have mentioned :-)

Comment: @MSeifert Does it? Python 3.5.2 and '1.12.1' for Numpy

Comment: @user2357112 Yes. I had some problems with Numpy and Python3, so I am running the script with python3.5 example.py command

Comment: Maybe the problem is round-off error in the floating point numbers. Does `choice()` allow for that?

Comment: Yes, If I specify the prob_list as [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4], it works..

Comment: The code that you have shown works for me.  We need to see the actual code that causes the problem. Ideally, you would create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.  Note that `numpy.random.choice` does not require that the numbers sum to *exactly* 1.  It tolerates an error as big as the square root of the floating point epsilon (specifically `np.sqrt(np.finfo(np.float64).eps)`, which is about 1.49e-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your evidence suggests that the numpy implementation of this function is broken.  It's almost certainly due to floating point roundoff, which can happen any time you try to add a bunch of floats together and expect it to come out exactly to a whole number (integer).  The traceback indicates that the function itself is written in C, and perhaps the translation from C to Python and back introduces yet another way for roundoff errors to accumulate.  The solution is to forget numpy and write the function in python, like this:

```
import random

def choice(x):
    r = random.randrange(sum(x))
    for a in x:
        r -= a
        if r < 0:
            return a

my_list = [11, 4, 2, 2, 1]  

for _ in range(10):
    print(choice(my_list))
```

This routine assumes that you have provided a list of ints, and avoids all float arithmetic.

BTW I don't know why this question has been downvoted.  It seems like a good question to me.

Comment: Others can't replicate the error; so it's not a problem with stock numpy.

Comment: It might be a problem with any version of numpy if it requires you to provide a list of floats that sum precisely to 1.000000000.  That's not an easy thing to do, and it might work with some lists but not others.  It could even be machine-dependent.  OP says that it works with [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4].  I claim it's better to bypass the whole issue and work with ints directly, since the function is simple.  And besides I already had it :-)

Comment: @PaulCornelius Thank you for your reply! It seems like a very good solution but I have to pick the numbers from `my_list`, with their weight considered. In here `choice()` function makes a random selection?

Comment: You can pass it any integer list, including your original my_list,  and it will pick one of the elements at random, weighted by the size of the elements.  Just like the numpy function except entirely using integers.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Just wondering, do you know how can I modify this code to pick two elements instead of one?

Comment: You could always just pop the selected item from the list and call the function again.  That's not very efficient, I suppose, but if you don't care about that it's easy to do.